# Update by Id not finding document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to perform a relatively simple update using Mongoose:

```
var location =  locationService.getLocation(typedLat, typedLong, travelRadius);

DocumentModel.update({_id :  passedInId }, { location : location }, function(err, resp){
    next(err, resp);
});
```

In this case passedInId is the string:
"561ee6bbe4b0f25b4aead5c8"

And in the object (test data I created) the id is:
"_id": ObjectId("561ee6bbe4b0f25b4aead5c8")

When I run the above however, matched documents is 0. I assume this is because passedInId is being treated like a string, however when I type it to an ObjectId:

```
var queryId = ObjectId(passedInId)
```

The result is the same, the document doesn't match.  What am I missing? This seems like it should be obvious....

Comment: setting the debug flag to true, it doesn't log the query to console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior was because I had not yet updated the model in mongoose to include the location element. There is no error, it just doesn't match or do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose will correctly interpret a string as an ObjectId. One of the following must be the case:

- That record is not in the collection. Run a query in the mongo shell to check.
- Mongoose I'd looking in collection other than the one containing your test data. Remember, by default,  mongo will lowercase the name under which you register your model and will add an a "s" to it.

  - Lastly, and your answer speaks to this, maybe your model it's just not being updated with any new information.

Comment: The object comes back with a findOne( { _id : ObjectId("561ee6bbe4b0f25b4aead5c8") }) and the model and document collection names match. Other methods around the same model have been working.